# Vectorizing Computation of Cosine Similarity Matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a matrix of 63695 row vectors of dim 384.

I would like to compute the cosine similarity model for this matrix.

I was thinking of vectorizing it.

How would one proceed to that objective?

Comment: Do you actively want to learn how to do this from scratch, or would you be happy using an out-of-the-box solution?  If out-of-the-box is ok, you could look at sklearn: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_similarity.html

Comment: @slothrop When I use that scikit function I get MemoryError: Unable to allocate 15.1 GiB for an array with shape (63695, 63695) and data type float32.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in scikit-learns source code you will see that `X` and `Y` are first normalized and then `X_norm @ Y_norm.T` (dot product) is returned. Or if as in your case no Y exists it is `X_norm @ X_norm.T`.

Normalizing and transposing can be discarded when looking at the runtime, but the matrix multiplaction of a `(63695 x 384)` matrix should take somewhere in the neighbourhood of `63695*63695` (elements in result matrix) times `384*384` (element-wise multiplactions and additions to calculate one element) calculations, so something like `63695*63695*384*384 = 598,236,810,854,400` operations. (Or strictly, that number of multiplications plus that same number of additions.)

And as you already mentioned it requires `4` (Bytes for float32) `* 63695 * 63695 = ~16.2 GB` of memory to handle that result matrix.

Do you really need that enormous matrix? What type of data are you handling and what are you trying to do? If we are talking about e.g. vector represenations of text data then you should look at removing duplicates, processing it in chunks or reducing the dimensionality before analysing similarity. If you are looking for something like ranking these cosine similarities and finding then k most similar ones you'd be much better of using algorithms for finding similar data points instead of doing it all by hand yourself.